# How to move newly generated file to particular location in tarfile

Tags: tar, gnu

I have a C file created :

```
 (
cat <<'End'
ifdef
 ...
 else
 ...
 endif
EOF) > $CFILE
```

and I want to move this new created c file to particular location in Tar file already generated.

```
tar -rvf $TARFILE "magically move CFILE to /foo/bar in tar file"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `tar`, by using `--transform` and specifying a `sed`-style substitution:

```
$ tar -rvf test.tar --transform 's#^#/here/it/is/#' .profile
.profile

$ tar tf test.tar
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/here/it/is/.profile
```

With BSD `tar`, by using `-s` in a similar (but not identical) way:

```
$ tar -rvf test.tar -s '#^#/here/it/is/#' .profile
/here/it/is/.profile

$ tar tf test.tar
tar: Removing leading / from absolute path names in the archive
here/it/is/.profile
```